# Custom `PT_INTERP` interpreter results in segmentation fault?

Tags: linux, debian, security, gcc, dynamic-linking

After having read [this](https://ctftime.org/writeup/10388) article on executing arbitrary programs by changing the `PT_INTERP` to a custom interpreter, I've tried to experiment with this locally:

```
$ cat flag.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("Hello World!\n");
    return 0;
}
$ gcc -static flag.c -o flag
$ cat solution.c
const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "./flag";
$ gcc -s -fno-ident -Wl,--build-id=none -Wl,-e,0 -static -nostdlib solution.c -o solution
$ ./solution
Segmentation fault
$ ./flag
Hello World!
```

> This `PT_INTERP` program header contains a path, which is the path of the interpreter (executable file) our ELF will run under

Since `solution` requests `./flag` as its interpreter, why doesn't `./flag` run and print the message "Hello World", when `solution` is executed? Instead a segmentation fault occurs, which is different from the behaviour in the article.

How can I successfully register and execute a custom interpreter in `PT_INTERP`?

```
$ readelf -l solution

Elf file type is EXEC (Executable file)
Entry point 0x0
There are 4 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  PHDR           0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000400040 0x0000000000400040
                 0x00000000000000e0 0x00000000000000e0  R      0x8
  INTERP         0x0000000000000120 0x0000000000400120 0x0000000000400120
                 0x0000000000000007 0x0000000000000007  R      0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: ./flag]
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x0000000000000127 0x0000000000000127  R      0x1000
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     0x10

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00
   01     .interp
   02     .interp
   03
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `dmesg`, you should see something like

```
(solution): Uhuuh, elf segment at 0000000000400000 requested but the memory is mapped already
```

The reason is that both `flag` and `solution` have a segment at 0x400000.

A quick way to avoid that is to use [the `tinyelf` `helloworld` binary](https://github.com/spencertipping/tinyelf) as `flag`; it doesn’t have a conflicting segment, and everything works.

Adapting the TinyELF example, write this to `flag.c`:

```c
#include <asm/unistd.h>

long syscall(long n,
             long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6);

void _start() {
  syscall(__NR_write, 1, (long) "Hello World!\n", 13, 0, 0, 0);
  syscall(__NR_exit, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

long syscall(long n, long a1, long a2, long a3, long a4, long a5, long a6) {
  asm volatile ("movq %4, %%r10;"
                                "movq %5, %%r8;"
                                "movq %6, %%r9;"
                                "syscall;"

                : "=a"(n)
                : "a"(n), "D"(a1), "S"(a2), "d"(a3),
                  "r"(a4), "r"(a5), "r"(a6)
                : "%r10", "%r8", "%r9");
  return n;
}
```

Build this as follows:

```sh
gcc -nostartfiles -nostdlib flag.c -o flag
```

Then the `solution` binary you already have will work.

Comment: Thanks. Isn’t that segment the base address of the ELF? Do you know a command to chance the base address (load address) of one the ELF binaries? TinyELF mentions that string literals are not allowed? Thus, I can’t use `printf`?

Comment: Yes, 0x400000 is the base address. I’d tried moving it to answer this question (using a linker script), and the resulting `flag` works, but `solution` still fails with a segfault during libc setup (`__current_locale_name`). The limitations in TinyELF are mostly related to the minimisation exercise, they’re not inherent in a loader; but libc does require some care.

Comment: But can I use string literals as function arguments then, when using TinyELF? It mentions that those cannot be used. Off-topic: since TinyELF must decide on base address for the final ELF, how can it prevent collisions with guarantee?

Comment: Have you looked at the implementation of TinyELF? It has a string literal... `ld.so` uses a load address of 0, as does TinyELF; as long as everything fits below 0x400000 you’ll be fine.

Comment: What I was referring too is the following excerpt from TinyELF: *obvious limitations are that you can't use libc or have any global data, including string literals*. I guess, it means exported string literals in this case that other compilation units may access, right?

Comment: I will accept your answer, although I had hoped for a solution only dependent on the `gcc` compiler suite

Comment: TinyELF was only intended as a quick workaround to show that a custom interpreter can be made to work, not as the solution in all cases. The limitation on global data comes from the `objcopy` processing used to produce a tiny binary; you don’t need that for an interpreter in general. You can produce a working interpreter using only GCC, the main limitation is that you can’t easily use the C library – you can take a look at how `ld.so` is implemented to deal with that, it’s not straightforward.

Comment: Thanks. So, a string in `printf("hello")` is not considered global data, since it's not exported to other compilation units, right? Would you comment on why zevzek's solution work? I see it's using a `ld` linker option to specify the dynamic-linker: `-I PROGRAM, --dynamic-linker PROGRAM`

Comment: `"hello"` in `printf("hello")` will typically end up as global data, stored in the `.rodata` section. That’s what causes problems for TinyELF; but it doesn’t have to be a problem for interpreters in general (`ld.so` contains lots of global data).

Comment: I found the solution. By omitting `-static` the resulting binary has no segment that loads at `0x40000`. Furthermore, the interpreter (`flag`) cannot depend on `libc`, even if `-static` is used, otherwise `dmesg` shows segfault in `solution`.

Comment: Indeed, see the update ;-).

Comment: Still, I feel the solution is very `gcc` dependent, because it's a fact that if using `-static`, then the load address becomes `0x40000`, and if omitting it and using `-e0` instead then the load address becomes `0x00` - not really something under our control

Comment: You don’t need `-e0`, and all this works with `clang` too.